# Method implementation in header not visible

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a noob question and would greatly appreciate an answer as to why my method defined in the header file is not visible to the calling classes. I have researched online and they all say that it should function as currently is.

main.cpp

```
#include "sort.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

std::vector<int> insertionVector = sort::insertionSort(data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(int));
```

sort.h

```
#include<vector>
namespace sort{
int* bubbleSort(const int *data, int size);
std::vector<int> insertionSort(const int *data, int size);

void swapValues(int* bigger, int* smaller){
    *bigger += *smaller;
    *smaller = *bigger - *smaller;
    *bigger = *bigger - *smaller;
}

}
```

InsertionSort.cpp

```
#include<vector>
namespace sort{

std::vector<int> insertionSort(const int *data, int size){
    std::vector<int> values(data,data+size);

    for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i){
        int j = i;
        while (j>0 && values.at(j - 1) > values.at(i)){
            swapValues(&values.at(j-1),&values.at(j));
            j--;
        }
    }
    return values;
}
}
```

I have tried inlining the swapValues method in sort.h but it has made no difference, the call in InsertionSort.cpp of swapValues says "error C3861:'swapValues': identifier not found. Why isn`t the method seen, when it is in the namespace and namespace is included ?
Thank you for your time helping me !

Comment: You have to include `sort.h` in `InsertionSort.cpp`

Comment: As a side note, you may want to look into using `std::swap()`.

Comment: Well, not precisely; rather `using std::swap; swap(a, b);`. Anyway, @OP, don't leave the `swapValues` definition in the header without it being `inline` or you could easily violate the One Definition Rule (in fact, if you're doing something like `g++ insertionSort.cpp main.cpp`, you already are).

Comment: Yes I have added inline as I ran into the issue you just mentioned, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InsertionSort.cpp` needs to include `sort.h` to get the declaration of `swapValues`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include sort.h in InsertionSort.cpp

```
#include "sort.h"
using namespace sort;
```

Comment: You don't want that using-directive though. That defeats the purpose of using a namespace in the first place.

Comment: Very simple solution indeed ... thank you ... I was under the impression that if they were in the same namespace they would know of each other from main ... thank you !